# Why Object.attribute is undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Javascript. I have two models `Unit` and `Site`.

A `Unit` has many `Sites`, this is how I pass them from the view:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="destroyUnit(unit.id, unit.sites)" ></a>
```

this is the function in my angularJS controller:

```
$scope.destroyUnit = function(unit_id, sites){
  console.log(unit_id)
  $scope.$emit("units.delete", unit_id, sites);
}

$scope.$on("units.delete", function(e, unit_id, sites){     
  console.log("unit_id: "+unit_id+", site_length: "+sites.length+", site_id "+sites[0].id);
});
```

This is the output which I get:

```
unit_id: 439, site_length: 2, site_id undefined
```

I just want to know why the `site_id` is `undefined`? and how can I get it? tnx.

### Update

For a better explanation; I just want to remove the `sites` from the `unit`; in this case the `site.id=443`

[image]

### update

I already tried `sites[0][0].id` but I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: What does sites[0] output? The id is probably just not present??

Comment: show relative code about your `sites`, or can't find out why.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it is clear that `sites` is an array with length as 2.

[image]

sites is an array variable assigned like

```
sites = [
         [{article: null, clip: {....}, id: 443}],
         [{...................}]
        ]
```

each item in `sites` is an array so you have to do like

```
sites[0][0].id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove a redundant `array wrap` in your code.

Now:

```
sites[0] // [{id: 443, ...}]
```

So, you only can access id by using

```
sites[0][0].id // 443
```

Now format:

```
sites: [[{article: null, clip: {....}, id: 443}], {}],
unit_id: 45
```

Correct format:

```
sites: [{article: null, clip: {....}, id: 443}, {}],
unit_id: 45
```